# Canonical Data Model Help

Tags: mental-models

I'm tasked with showing a model (from a business perspective) how 4 systems are being incoporated into one model (like a common data model).  The data model is very high-level (non technical) and representing that information in a data dictionary.  I'm getting stuck on how to represent it in a data dictionary because I have data coming from multiple systems.  How do you represent the same data element from different systems in a way that makes sense and looks good and provides explanation on what the particular field means from a business perspective?  Any examples would be greatly appreciative and/or a place to look on the internet anywhere or particular site?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi B. Thompson, thank you for contributing to our pool of knowledge at UXSE! The best way to learn and get help is to also give it a go and show your thought process, and that way when people provide an answer we can learn and share between all the community members :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need a way to detail **1)** what the properties represent, and **2)** where they can possibly come from.

Perhaps some variation of the following data table can concisely communicate the necessary details.

For this example, let's imagine the object in question is a "user profile" object that is being constructed from data collected over several applications.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f95o0k.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>